# What will happen if three equal tornadoes compressed together in one axis?

Tags: vortex

Imagine, 3 completely equal tornadoes with similar spin are compressing together by huge outer force in one axis and we can control the amount of outer force, what will happen as we gradually increase that force? How these tornadoes change their shapes, spins,relations for adaptation ?

Comment: How do you plan to push wind around? Do you plan for your force to slow it down? Deflect it? It is hard to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

A tornado is basically a [vortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex) line. Two or more vortices with the same direction of circulation will tend to attract each other, and they will eventually merge into one with a summed circulation.

This is called the [Fujiwhara effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujiwhara_effect) in the case of cyclonic vortices. In the case of tornadoes, there are sometimes [satellite tornadoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_tornado) circulating around the main one and sometimes merging.

So the issue is not so much forcing the tornadoes together as keeping them apart.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tornados are conserved vortex lines, but an even simpler view, just to get started, is, it's a hole in the atmosphere. That's why the cloud base dips down to the ground to meet you, and the local air rushes (I mean *rushes*) in to fill it.

My notes say the *EF* number scales to windspeed (mph) via:

$$ V_{\rm mph} = 1.32623732(EF+6.80405916)^{2.03088117}$$

so if it gets 3x stronger...use that to figure out the new *EF* and report back.